# How to modify web.config when not deploying from source

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to add a rewrite rule to web.config for https.

When creating a Wordpress site from the Gallery, how would I configure the web.config that is created automatically? Using ftp, I can't overwrite the file. It just disappears from the ftp session and is still the old version.

Of course I could download the entire site and then re-deploy via git with full controll, but it's kind of convenient to just let wordpress do updates directly on the production site.

Any other options?

Answer (score 4):

Or you can use the "Debug Console" by going to 
https://your_site_name.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole, 
then go to .\site\wwwroot\ and edit web.config directly by clicking the "pencil" icon on the left of the file.

Comment: +1 for the DebugConsole link...had no idea this even existed!

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio online does the trick. Found in the Configure tab, but still Preview.